# How could I rewrite an NFC sticker link using ReactJS to a specific profile

Tags: reactjs, nfc, open-nfc

I'm trying to figure out how I could have a set of NFC stickers that all link to the login page of a React web app, the user could then sign up to create a profile and this would link the NFC sticker to their specific profile

Every time the sticker is then tapped it would link to their specific profile (webapp.com/profilename) rather than the original landing page.

I am working on my final year project and need some advice, seen it be done before but cannot work out how they're doing it

Answer (score 1):

You would write an NDEF message that contains the URI you want to open in a browser.

ReactJS example on how to write an NDEF URI message at https://github.com/whitedogg13/react-native-nfc-manager/blob/master/example/AppV2Ndef.js

Just change the `let bytes = buildUrlPayload('https://www.revteltech.com');`

to be the URL you want.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, going to have a proper look into it!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Web NFC to write NDEFMessage with a URL record.

Here's some working code you can try in Chrome for Android:

```js
const ndef = new NDEFReader();
await ndef.write({
  records: [{ recordType: "url", data: "https://webapp.com/profilename" }]
});
```

Full documentation is available at https://web.dev/nfc/